# Using Arraylist in different classes

Tags: java, arraylist

So the code below finds words in a document as specific by the word input. Counts the number of times the words occurs in each sentence then stores that count in the arraylists at the bottom label a for cone and b for ctwo.

I want to use the arraylists in another class but can't seem to find a way to do it.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class exc {

    public exc() {
        }
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception     {
cone aa = new cone();
ctwo bb = new ctwo();
// after this I'm stuck

}
}
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.FileReader;
        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.List;

public class cone {

public  void cone() throws Exception     {

                    BufferedReader e = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words to be read.txt"));
                        String o;
                        while((o = e.readLine()) != null){

                            String[] sentences = o.split("\\b[.!?]\\s+");

                        //System.out.println(o);
                            String [] h = sentences;

                        {

                            BufferedReader t = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Text to be scan.txt"));
                            String g;
                            while((g = t.readLine()) != null){  

                                String[] set=g.split(" ");

                                List<String> list = Arrays.asList(set);

                            //  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set));
                                //System.out.println(o);

                            int sentenceNumb=1;
                            for (String sentence: h) {
                                int counter=0;
                                String[] words = sentence.replace(".", "").split(" ");
                                for(String word: words) {
                                    if (list.contains(word)) {
                                        counter++;
                                    }  
                                }


                               List<Integer> A = Arrays.asList(counter++);

                            }


                            }



                        }
                        }

}
}

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class ctwo {


public  void ctwo() throws Exception     {

BufferedReader e = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words to be read.txt"));
    String o;
    while((o = e.readLine()) != null){

        String[] sentences = o.split("\\b[.!?]\\s+");

    //System.out.println(o);
        String [] h = sentences;

    {

        BufferedReader t = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Text to be scan.txt"));
        String g;
        while((g = t.readLine()) != null){  

            String[] set=g.split(" ");

            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(set);

        //  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set));
            //System.out.println(o);

        int sentenceNumb=1;
        for (String sentence: h) {
            int counter=0;
            String[] words = sentence.replace(".", "").split(" ");
            for(String word: words) {
                if (list.contains(word)) {
                    counter++;
                }  
            }


           List<Integer> B= Arrays.asList(counter++);

        }


        }



    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Make both methods return the `ArrayList`s?

Answer (score 1):

1. Best approach: You have both the ArrayLists in main(), pass them as function parameters to functions(from any class) that need them.
2. Not so good approach: Store the ArrayLists as package protected static class variables in the cone and ctwo classes. You can access them as cone.A and ctwo.B.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the same array list in the constructor of both the classes.

Comment: How? I'm new to java how do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

your program seems weird.
I would suggest reading words and adding distinct words to hashmap with key as word and value as it's count.

Comment: how can I do this?